# Android: associate a button with a value, that the user cannot see

Tags: java, android, button, text

I want to have a value (e.g. integer 17) associated with a button. When the button is clicked I want to retrieve that value. How do I do that?

I am reading [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) since button extends `TextView`. I've scanned the `XML` attributes but I cannot find anything. I was thinking about something like casting the View that I get in my activity method to a `(Button)` and then call something like

```
int my_database_int = button.getValue()
```

I find it hard to believe that there is no such functionality?

Comment: I dont know why you want to get value from button only? Are you storing any value in button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property for `Button` objects in which you can store almost anything,  
and this is the tag:

```
int myvalue = 10;
button.setTag(myValue);
```

and then get it like:

```
int my_database_int = Integer.parseInt(button.getTag().toString());
```

You can also define the tag's value in xml:

```
android:tag="10"
```

Comment: ahhh thank you so much, that is exactly what I meant!! and I know why I didn't find it: it's an xml attribute of [the father class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:tag) of textview (which is view).

Comment: It's commonly used for cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `android:tag="value"` attribute in your XML and use `button.getTag()` in your java class. The method returns a object you have to typecast to your desired format.

Answer (score -2):

Try button.getId() in Java file. It will return integer unique id of button view